# Change GridView Custom Button Text and Css on click event

Tags: css, asp.net, button, gridview, webforms

I am working on a project where I am creating a dashboard for the Admin.
I have a **UsersGridView** which displays the data of the registered users in it.
Using the **Template** field for the **Gridview** I have created a button for that allows the **Admin** to with **Lockout** or **Enable** the user's to use the system.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LockoutStatus">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="LockoutStatus" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="LockoutStatus" Text="Enabled"
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In the **RowCommand** event how can I change the button CssClass and text if the user is locked out from the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can change the CssClass.

With the RowDataBound event.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is d datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the row back to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //use findcontrol to locate the butotn
        Button btn = e.Row.FindControl("LockoutStatus") as Button;

        //change the class based on a column value
        if (row["ColumnName"].ToString() == "LockedOut")
        {
            btn.CssClass = "ClassA";
        }
    }
}
```

Or on the aspx page with a ternary operator.

```
<asp:Button ID="LockoutStatus" runat="server" 
    CssClass='<%# Eval("ColumnName").ToString() == "LockedOut" ? "ClassA" : "ClassB" %>'
```

Or as you wanted in the RowCommand event. You can use the CommandSource and cast it to a Button.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = e.CommandSource as Button;
    btn.CssClass = "ClassA";
}
```